# Selenium only extracts a fragment of elements inside a div

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get all the fields' values inside a div, and for some reason the collection seems to stop at the first class that doesn't match the given name (even though there are other matching fields later). Here is the HTML code for the div:

```
<div class="dataContainer">
 <div class"dataField">...</div>
 <div class"dataField">...</div>
 <div class"dataField">...</div>
 <div class"anoterDataField">...</div>
 <div class"dataField">...</div>
 <div class"anoterDataField">...</div>
 <div class"anoterDataField">...</div>
 <div class"dataField">...</div>
</div>
```

And here is my code that collects the elements:

```
WebElement dataContainer = driver.findElement(By.className("dataContainer));
List<WebElement> dataFields = dataContainer.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dataField' or @class='anotherDataField']/input"));
```

However, when I pass the dataFields to a processor function, it will onlz contain the first 3 fields' value.

What is the proper way to collect the value of every `dataField` and `anotherDataField`?

Comment: Do the other div's contain a input element immediately?

Comment: Blimey, they don't... I only checked the first couple ones, and those were the same. Also, later on there are some other type of input fields as well. Can I use the xpath like this: "//div[@class='dataField']/input or @class='anotherDataField']/div/input"

Comment: Switch it to - //div[@class='dataField' or @class='anotherDataField']//input - Extra slash '/' in front of input will take care of skipping elements in between

Comment: This worked, now it collects everything (and some more). Now I'm facing another issue, where the input fields are read-only and the values are not extracted, but that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: The text displayed should be in the 'value' attribute of the inpuy element